# Como faço para que a cada clique os números fiquem registados na Base de Dados?

Tags: html

Fiz um contador parecido com a "chamada do número seguinte " numa instituição bancaria e queria que quando eu chamasse por exemplo o Nº 1 que esse numero 1 ficasse gravado na base de dados e quando chamasse o numero 2 que esse também fique gravado na BD e assim por diante ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


var Cont1 = 0;
function balcao1(){
Cont1 = Cont1 + 1;
document.getElementById('contador1').value = Cont1;
}


    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    #contador1{
        font:bold 150px Arial;
        padding: 50px;
        color:#FF0000;
        border:2px dashed #f1f1f1;
        width:350px;
        height:350px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 200px;
    }



    .btn{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left:130px;
    }
</style>
</head>


<body>

        <div class="col-md-3">
    <center><h1><span class="label label-default">Senha A </span></h1></center>
    <input id="contador1"><br>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Pr&oacute;ximo" onclick="balcao1();">
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem, você quer que quando o numero aparecer na "tela" ele seja gravado no banco de dados?

Comment: O que vc conhece sobre linguagem de programação e banco de dados? Qual linguagem está usando, ou pretende? A mesma pergunta para o banco de dados.

Comment: é tipo isso sim ... vou ser mais especifico ... não sou muito bom em php para gravar os dados na BD ... mas é tipo quando preenchemos um formulario e clicamos em ENVIAR e os dados ficam na BD pois é mesma ideia que quero aqui que quando eu clicar no botão PROXIMO que o nº1 fique gravado , depois quando clicar novamente que o nº 2 fique tb gravado e ai por diante ... por favor me ajude

Comment: KaduAmaral ... eu conheço mais de html e css e um pouco de base de dados no que diz respeito a pesquisas na base de dados mas no que diz respeito a php não sei realmente nada ... e como para gravar os numeros na base de dados é preciso php por isso estou aqui pedindo a vossa ajuda ... obrigado

Comment: @UchihaBruno postei a resposta

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda vou fazer tudo se me puderes enviar o teu facebook para falarmos melhor agradeceria bastante , porque nunca ninguem me ajudou assim como tu diretamente , já que sou novo aqui no stack , abraço

Comment: @UchihaBruno blz , voce tem que colocar como pergunta respondida então

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Salvando o numero do seu código em um banco utilizando PHP:

Você pode utilizar uma requisição AJAX para acessar uma pagina PHP e salvar a variável no baco de dados, conforme implementado no seu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Contador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var Cont1 = 0;
function balcao1(){

Cont1 = Cont1 + 1;
document.getElementById('contador1').value = Cont1;

//AQUI A REQUISIÇÃO AJAX

    $.ajax({
        //pode ser post ou get
        type: "GET",

        //url aonde a pagina php responsavel por salvar no banco está.
        url: "registra_banco.php?valor=Cont1",

        //você está passando o valor de Cont1 via get para a pagina registra_banco.php

        cache: false,

        success: function (retorno) {
            alert("salvo no banco de dados!);
        },
        error: function(retorno) {
            alert("erro!);
        }
    });

}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

    #contador1{
        font:bold 150px Arial;
        padding: 50px;
        color:#FF0000;
        border:2px dashed #f1f1f1;
        width:350px;
        height:350px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 200px;
    }

    .btn{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left:130px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <center><h1><span class="label label-default">Senha A </span></h1></center>
  <input id="contador1"><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Pr&oacute;ximo" onclick="balcao1();">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Bom vale lembrar que o ajax é da biblioteca jquery. ele está enviando o valor para a pagina registra_banco.php via get (pela url) e assim posteriormente ser salvo no banco de dados

**Exemplo de como ficaria a pagina registra_banco.php:**

```
<?php

//abre uma conexão com o banco de dados, esses parametros variam de como foi feito seu banco de dados
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data_dashboard", "root", "" );

//pega o valor passado via ajax e atribui a uma variavel 

if (isset($_GET['valor'])) {
  $valor= $_GET['valor'];
}

//agora que você tem o valor você precisa dar um insert no seu banco de dados
//monta a query que será executada no banco (depende de como está sua tabela tambem) 
$query = "insert into valores values('$valor')";

//rode o metodo de executar a sua query no banco 
$db->execute($query);

?>
```

Se na sua tela aparecer o alert de salvo, é porque a requisição ajax deu certo, se der error, é porque a requisição ajax falhou

> Lembrando que existem inumeras maneiras de se fazer isso, nesse método
>   foram usados POO e AJAX., para se aprofundar na classe de conexão com
>   o banco de dados do php :

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

e para ajax recomendo:

http://www.devfuria.com.br/javascript/ajax-php-jquery/